# "Spark" is not defined - Creating Python UDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, databricks, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a python UDF in Databricks. While the code below deploys fine, when I attempt to call the function by passing a legit argument to it, I get an error. I know the logic is correct because when I run the python code in a separate cell, it returns the value expected.

```
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myUDF(serial_input INT)
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE PYTHON
AS
$$
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F

  df = spark.sql("Select serial, datetime, count_of_runs from mysqltableinDBX")
  totalcounts = df.filter(df.serial == serial_input).agg(F.sum(df.count_of_runs )).collect()[0][0]
  return totalcounts 

$$
```

Here is how I am calling the function in sql.

```
%sql
select myUDF(71605) as UDF_Result
```

The error I receive is "SparkRuntimeException: [UDF_USER_CODE_ERROR.GENERIC] Execution of function failed" error.
If I expand this it says "NameError: name 'spark' is not defined"

Can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: Isn't `spark` supposed to be an object of `SparkSession` class? Additionally there seems to be no `sql` method in `pysark.sql.functions`, which invalidates your use of `sql` method.

Comment: If thats the case, how can i use a python function in sql?

Comment: You should import `pyspark.sql.SparkSession` in your python script to use the `sql` method directly, i.e.,`from pyspark.sql import SparkSession`, then you can use `SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()` method to create a SparkSession instance and use the previously imported `sql` method on this object.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your code:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
```

then do:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.sql("Select serial, datetime, count_of_runs from mysqltableinDBX")
```

Comment: I did that and still get the same error.

Comment: This is strange. Try to open a new notebook and install and import from the scratch. it should work.

Comment: Strange, I get a different error, but is related 
== Error ==
SystemExit: -1
== Stacktrace ==
  File "<udfbody>", line 5, in main
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

Comment: == SQL(line 1, position 8) ==
select myUDF(71605) as UDF_Result
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^